Identify a Solitaire game from the 70's
I'm looking to find the name of the game my grandfather taught me back in the 70s.

Deal: It was played with two decks.  There are two rows of cards dealt.  Top row is dealt face down and counted out A-7 as you go.  Bottom row beneath that is dealt mostly face down-- 8,9,10 and then a FACE UP draw pile, then three more piles, J Q K.  Total of 14 piles with one face up draw pile.

Win: object is to create 8 foundation piles, four A-K per suit and the other four K-A per suit.

Play: Pick a card from the draw pile.  If the card is, say, a 4, you pick up pile #4 and hold it like a hand.  You can arrange the cards in that pile in any way you think you may need them for the foundation piles.  One to the next card in the draw pile, until you're finished.


The idea is to be able to arrange the cards in a helpful way and hopefully get all cards to the foundation piles.  HARD to win, as a kid I was addicted.  My grandfather played a LOT of solitaire and never told me the name of this, or maybe he didn't know.  Or maybe it's a bogus variation of something.  He was super smart, an engineer, born in 1918, so the game may be older.
Thanks for any input!  :D

I use the World of Solitaire site to play. There's over 100 variations there. Yours doesn't sound familiar - but I only tend to play the same 4 or 5 games. Might be worth checking out. https://worldofsolitaire.com/

The use of two decks and the objective to create foundation piles from Ace to King and King to Ace is reminiscent of Klondike, but the specific setup of piles suggests additional elements.
